# Can someone try .padStart javascript in Adobe pro?

Tags: javascript, adobe

```
var n = 11; 
this.getField("Text1").value = n; 
var pad = String(n).padStart(3, '0'); 
this.getField("Text2").value = pad;
```

shouldn't the above produce: [in Text 1] 11, [in Text 2] 011? it does nothing for me.

and this:

```
this.getField("Text3").value = String(1).padStart(3, '0');
```

should produce: [in Text 3] 001? again, does nothing for me.

why would the fields (Text 2 and Text 3) be blank for me?

Comment: IIRC, Adobe products don't use JS, but [tag:extendscript], a subset of modern JS which is based on and locked at ES3 (1999). `.padStart()` was, on the other hand, added in ES6 (2015)...